# insert into timestamp oracle column from java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

i got a table made in this way

```
CREATE TABLE WS_NAPACQ00T
( IDE_IDEN varchar2(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  CLB_CXML CLOB,
  SYS_DATE TIMESTAMP
);
```

and this java code to put in dt_date current date.

```
Timestamp dt_date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
String insertXML = "insert into WS_NAPACQ00T (IDE_IDEN, CLB_CXML, SYS_DATE) values ('10', 'test', '"+dt_date+"' ) ";
result = statement.executeQuery(insertXML);
```

the error is:

```
"not a valid month"
```

how can i resolve?

Comment: you need to convert the java timestamp into oracle timestamp format..

Comment: how is possible convert from java timestamp into oracle timestamp?

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` (side benefit of protection against SQL injection) and call `setTimestamp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) it can lead to [SQLInjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), instead use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) as follows.

```
String insertXML = "insert into WS_NAPACQ00T (IDE_IDEN, CLB_CXML, SYS_DATE) values (?, ?, ?) ";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(insertXML);
statement.setString(1,"10");
statement.setString(2,"test");
statement.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
result = statement.executeQuery();
```

*Unrelated.*

If you want to insert current timestamp you can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from DUAL;` will give the current timestamp.

Comment: Perfect, it runs well. but apart the security, i don't understand why with prepared statement it runs ok, but with normal statement it goes in error.

Comment: In normal statement you have to construct the query as you do in a SQL client like sqlplus.